# NASM linked with C offset

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, calling-convention

I'm building a bare bone execution environment for C, bootstrapped via a bootloader. Bootstrapping the executable works well, but I am unable to call asm routines from C. I have defined a function 'putchar' in ASM which should be callable from C. The problem is that from the looks of it during debugging all calls to the nasm compiled assembly appears to be a few bytes off.

C source code is as follows:

```
#include "io.h"

void kmain() {
    putchr('!', 5);
    while(1);
}
```

With `io.h`:

```
extern void putchr(char c, int repeat);
```

This compiles into:

```
│0x600 <kmain>           push 
│0x601 <kmain+1>         mov    bp,sp
│0x603 <kmain+3>         sub    sp,0x18
│0x606 <kmain+6>         mov    WORD PTR [si+0x24],0x504
│0x60b <kmain+11>        add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
│0x60d <kmain+13>        add    bh,al
│0x60f <kmain+15>        add    al,0x24
│0x611 <kmain+17>        and    WORD PTR [bx+si],ax
│0x613 <kmain+19>        add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
│0x615 <kmain+21>        call   0x625 ; Should be call to putchr
│0x618 <kmain+24>        add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al 
│0x61a <kmain+26>        jmp    0x61a <kmain+26> ; I suppose this is while(1)
```

putchr is defined in assembly and calls another internal function there:

```
bits 32

global putchr

    nop
    nop
    nop
    xor eax, eax
    nop
    nop

putchr:
    ; PutChar expects: al = character (first arg), cx = repeat (second arg)
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp + 8] ; First arg
    and eax, 0xFF      ; Only interested in lower 8 bytes (8-bit al register)

            ; Note at this point eax = 0xc3/195 and not 0x21/33 as I'd expect

    mov cx, [ebp + 12] ; Second arg
    call PutChar
```

The call to putchr is wrong, because putchr is not at `0x625` but the second to last `nop` of the top of my assembly file is there. `putchr` starts at `0x627`. I suppose this is also the cause that I cannot read the values passed ('!' and 5) from C.

I'm compiling and linking as follows:

```
nasm -f elf32 -F dwarf -g io.asm -o ../build/os/imm/asm/io.o
gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -gdwarf-4 -m32 -ggdb3 -c kernel.c -o ../build/os/imm/c/kernel.o
ld -m elf_i386 -nmagic -Tos.lds  ../build/os/imm/c/kernel.o  ../build/os/imm/asm/io.o -o ../build/os/os
```

With the linker script `os.lds` being fairly basic and straightforward:

```
    ENTRY(kmain);

PHDRS { 
    headers PT_PHDR FILEHDR PHDRS; 
    code PT_LOAD;
}

SECTIONS {
    .text 0x600: ALIGN(0x100) { *(.text) } :code
    .data : { *(data) }
    .bss : { *(bss) }
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) }
}
```

Why is there such weird offset of 0x2 and why can't the function arguments be picked up from the assembly implementation?

Comment: From a quick glance, you are mixing 16 and 32 bit code. It's not obvious how you managed to compile your `kmain` as 16 bit?

Comment: According to the command line parameters (`-m32`) everything is compiled as 32 bits, in addition to a `bits 32` in the assembler file.

Comment: Actually I think your `kmain` is 32 bit, you just disassembled it wrongly as 16 bit. Now the question is of course, what mode do you run it in? If you haven't switched to 32 bit protected mode, the cpu will execute code as 16 bit and that won't work.

Comment: You're right. `kmain` is compiled as 32-bit. However, if I compile with `-m16` a CPU crash occurs when exiting the routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the issue unfortunately, but I was using 16-bit C since I wanted to get *something* working after fiddling for a while. Switching back to 32-bit I finally found the issue:

```
mov esp, [stack]
```

Instead of setting `esp` to the address of the stack, I was setting it to the *value* of the stack. OSDev wiki was not wrong pointing out that OS development might cause debugging for hours before seeing the answer right in front of your face!